# What is wrong with this form? It does not seem to post (get)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, get

See the search form of this website in question:

http://www.xyzai.com/academia/

It just defaults back to the original main page.

This is very odd, because it seems the form is set up properly.

```
<form action="http://www.xyzai.com/academia/" class="search-form standard-search" method="get" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">        
        <input type="search" title="Search for:" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search …" class="search-field form-control">            
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default search-submit" type="submit" id="searchsubmit"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i></button>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

What is causing this?

BY REQUEST, MORE INFO:

It appears when Wordpress's permalinks are turned off (default settings) things work great. Otherwise, no search is accomplished.

Comment: Maybe the page being submitted to redirects or there is a rewrite rule in .htdocs or something. Nobody can answer this based on the amount of info you've given.

Comment: That at least is a clue, thank you. It appears it might be redirecting.

Comment: What does you .htaccess file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Buddypress was hijacking wordpress's search.

I had to add this to wp-config.php

define ( 'BP_SEARCH_SLUG', 'find' );